# Creating a dynamic site map page for an asp.net application - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I have created a ASP.Net application which basically serves as a content management site. I need to create a Sitemap for our website which should be dynamic. I've tried Telerik's Sitemap control for ASP.net Ajax and found it useful. I want to know which is the best way to create a dynamic site map page in an ASP.net application before i proceed with the telerik control.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing which version of .NET you are using, it's a bit difficult to give a single answer.

One approach compatible with ASP.NET 2.0 is documented at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/dynamicsitemap.aspx.

If you're using ASP.NET 3.5 or higher, and can use LINQ, you can derive a class from `StaticSiteMapProvider`, as shown in http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=281&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1.